# Why does the Catholic Church require miracles for someone to be canonized?

Tags: catholicism, saint, canonization

Why does someone have to have a miracle (or two) attributed to them before they can  officially become a Saint? Why isn't clear evidence of a righteous lifestyle enough?

Comment: Or a clear profession of faith?

Comment: Matthew 16:4 "A wicked and adulterous generation seeketh after a sign; and there shall no sign be given unto it, but the sign of the prophet Jonas. And he left them, and departed."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Why does someone have to have a miracle (or two) attributed to them before they can officially become a Saint? [...]*

Understood as asking,

**"Why is there a formal Canonization process within the Church and why are miracles required when** *'clear evidence of a righteous [life ought to be sufficient]'*?"

The latter part of the question is answered by this article [Beatification and Canonization | New Advent](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/02364b.htm):

> The Catholic Church canonizes or beatifies only those whose lives have
>   been marked by the exercise of [**heroic virtue**](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/07292c.htm), and only after
>   this has been proved by common repute for sanctity and by conclusive
>   arguments.

*Why a formal process?*

The answer is in the formula of canonization such as the one below:

> Therefore, today, in a solemn Mass in St. Peter's Square, before an
>   immense multitude of the faithful, We have pronounced the following
>   formula: **In honor of the Blessed and Undivided Trinity, for the
>   uplifting of Catholic faith and the increase of Christian life, by the
>   authority of our Lord Jesus Christ and that of the Holy Apostles Peter
>   and Paul and our own, after careful deliberation, having called
>   frequently upon God's help, and with the advice of many of our brother
>   Bishops**, We declare and define Blessed *N* to be a Saint, and We
>   inscribe his name in the catalogue of the Saints, ordaining that,
>   throughout the universal Church, he be devoutly honored among the
>   Saints. In the name of the Father and of the Son and of the Holy
>   Spirit.

Since raising someone to the altars honors the Blessed Trinity and will be for the uplifting of the Catholic faith and increase of the Christian life, the act was preceded *by careful deliberation, calling frequently upon God's help, and with the advice of many Bishops.*

*Why are miracles required?*

People may be mistaken about a person's reputation for sanctity but not God. Before the real [Marcial Maciel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcial_Maciel) came to light, if one went by the works he founded, one might think he were a living saint.

The article Beatification and Canonization | New Advent quoted above states:

> the Church [sees] in the saints nothing more than friends and servants
>   of God whose holy lives have made them worthy of His special love.

After Jesus performs a miracle whereby a man born blind receives sight, the gospels testify that, [*'[we] know that God does not listen to sinners, but if any one is a worshiper of God and does his will, God listens to him.'*](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%209%3A31&version=RSVCE)

Therefore the miracles wrought through the intercession of the friends and servants of God testify to the now definitive friendship in heaven in God's presence.

---

**Endnotes:**

1. Please note that there are saints in heaven not formally canonized whose Solemnity [All Saints] is celebrated on November 1.
2. [Saint Paul referred to Christians as "saints"](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Corinthians%201%3A2&version=RSVCE). This is the calling for everyone.
3. For canonizations, the pope may, and does, use one of two methods, each constituting a new species of canonization, i.e. *formal canonization and equivalent canonization.* [cf. the New advent article linked above].

---

Further reading:

- [APOSTOLIC CONSTITUTION *DIVINUS PERFECTIONIS MAGISTER* | Pope St. John Paul II [the Great]](http://www.vatican.va/holy_father/john_paul_ii/apost_constitutions/documents/hf_jp-ii_apc_25011983_divinus-perfectionis-magister_en.html).
- [NEW LAWS FOR THE CAUSES OF SAINTS *promulgated in 1983* | CONGREGATION FOR THE CAUSES OF SAINTS](http://www.vatican.va/roman_curia/congregations/csaints/documents/rc_con_csaints_doc_07021983_norme_en.html).

Please note **Can. 1403 §1**.

> Special pontifical law<sup>1</sup> governs the causes of canonization of the
>   servants of God.

<sup>1. Please see the preceding bullet points.</sup>

Comment: One additional note - there are also people who are considered saints but were not formally canonized by the standard process (e.g. St. Peter, St. Lucy, most of the early saints).

Comment: @MattGutting Thanks! You are welcome to edit in and expand upon where you see fit. Perhaps in the endnotes?